# AnyLogic: understand which agaent has sent the message in statechart

Tags: anylogic

is there anyway to reach to the agent #1 which has sent a message (for example text message) to agent #2 inside action part of the transition of statechart of agent#2. I need to know some features of the agent which has sent the message (#1).

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the connections element, where messages are received by an agent, you have access to the sender... 
Check the connection element properties, under the communication section as seen in the following image:

[image: connections properties]

Remember that whenever you send a message, the message is managed by the connections element and sent to all the statecharts from there.